# Google Calendar - Get shareable link via API / get 'cid' value for a calendar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

Can I get a Google Calendar's 'cid' value via the API?

The 'id' returned in a Google Calendar Service API [list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList)/[insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) function is not very useful (unlike the usefulness of the 'id' when working with Google Drive service). Using the returned 'id' I can build a URL to the public calendar, but what I really want to do is build the URL to add the calendar to your calendars.  The same one that is made when you go to a calendar's settings and click "Get Shareable Link".

The shareable link looks like this:

> https://calendar.google.com/calendar?cid=reallyLongSequenceOfLettersAndNumber

If I can just get that 'cid' value programmatically...

Here is the data returned when using the API to list calendars:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116392/how-to-get-a-link-to-add-a-google-calendar).

It turns out the 'id' returned is the 'cid' in base64 encoding. Apparently *sometimes* the original 'id' will work as the 'cid'.. reference the link above for more info.

My python function to translate the 'id' into base64 is as follows:

```
    def getCalenderCID(calendarId):
        calendarId_bytes = calendarId.encode('utf-8')
        cid_base64 = base64.b64encode(calendarId_bytes)
        cid = cid_base64.decode().rstrip('=')
        return cid
```